# Leiningen freezing on console input

Tags: clojure, leiningen, console-input

Why does trying to read a line from console with a BufferedReader freeze Leiningen REPL?

```
lein repl
nREPL server started on port 65142
REPL-y 0.2.0
Clojure 1.5.1
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)

user=> (import [java.io BufferedReader BufferedWriter InputStreamReader])
java.io.InputStreamReader
user=> (.readLine (BufferedReader. (InputStreamReader. System/in)))
```

Comment: Try (read-line) see if the same thing happens

Comment: https://www.refheap.com/52027 mabe try downgrading to lein 2.1.2 (my version, works as you see in the paste)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `lein repl` actually launches a new background server process for evaluating code; what you see in the console is a client process that sends code to the server for evaluation and then displays the results that are returned. What I suspect is happening here is that, when the REPL server evaluates `System/in`, it's actually referring to stdin of the server process, which you can't write to from the client.

Replacing `(InputStreamReader. System/in)` with `*in*` should allow your code to work from the REPL as well as when launched directly with `lein run` or `java`.